# jqGrid Export To PDF (Highlighted Row)

Tags: jqgrid

I'm exporting a jqGrid to PDF that works fine with one exception. The printout doesn't include highlighted rows in the grid.  For example, I'm highlighting certain row as follows

```
$("#inventoryOnHandSearchGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', i, false, "css-class");
```

The "css-class" is just a css class that sets the background color

```
background-color: lightyellow;
```

This is the code to export

```
 $("#inventoryOnHandSearchGrid").jqGrid("exportToPdf", {
        title: 'Quantity On Hand',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        pageSize: 'A3',
        description: "Date: " + todaysDate,
        customSettings: null,
        download: 'download',
        includeLabels: true,
        includeGroupHeader: true,
        includeFooter: true,
        fileName: "qtyOnHand.pdf"
    })
```

Is this possible to have the export show the highlighted rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Guriddo jqGrid the exportToPdf does not convert html to pdf - it uses pdfMake to generate the pdf based on the raw array data.

Partial solution is to use onBeforeExport event to modify document so that it can color a rows by condition.

The example below make export to pdf in zebra table

```
$("#inventoryOnHandSearchGrid").jqGrid("exportToPdf", {
...
    onBeforeExport : function( doc ) {
        doc.content[2].layout = {};
        doc.content[2].layout.fillColor = function(rowIndex, node) {
            return (rowIndex % 2 === 0) ? '#CCCCCC' : null;
        };
    },
...
});
```

For more information look at the [pdfMake documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.3/)